# PyQt5 window crashes when socket is continue running in background

Tags: python, api, socket.io, pyqt, pyqt5

I have written a python code using **PyQt5** and **"socketIO_client_nexus"**. which will initiate socket connection as a client which will read the response from the server when "s_id" method trigger using `socketIO.on'

after getting SocketID I have to stop the socketIO in order to save window from crashing window. if I do not stop socketIO PyQt5 window will automatically crash

Please help me with an option through which I can solve this issue

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QLineEdit, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QThread
import requests
import json
import sys
from socketIO_client_nexus import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
import logging
import requests

class SendInvitation(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, arg):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(240, 500))
        self.setWindowTitle("GetUserlist")

        self.userid = arg

        url = 'http://192.168.2.36:5200/get_userlist'
        head = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        data = {'user_id': self.userid}

        ret = requests.post(url, data, head)
        responcedict = json.loads(ret.content)
        print(responcedict)
        userData = responcedict['data']
        x=100
        y=100
        for i in userData:
            useridstring = str(i['user_id'])

            buttonname = QPushButton(useridstring, self)
            buttonname.move(20, y)
            y= y + 30

            buttonname = QPushButton(i['user_name'],self)
            buttonname.move(120, x)
            x = x+30

        self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel.setText('Enter Opponant ID: ')
        self.line1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line1.move(120, 25)
        self.line1.resize(100, 25)
        self.nameLabel.move(20, 20)

        OKbutton = QPushButton('OK', self)
        OKbutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        OKbutton.resize(100,32)
        OKbutton.move(80, 60)

    def clickMethod(self):
        self.OpponantID = self.line1.text()
        print("Invitation send ID:" + self.OpponantID)
        # return OpponantID

        def getSID(args):
            # print(userid)
            NOWsocketID = args
            print("YOUR SocketID: " + NOWsocketID)
            url = 'http://192.168.2.36:5200/start_game'
            head = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            data = {'user_id': self.userid,
                    'opponent_id': self.OpponantID,
                    'socket_id': NOWsocketID}
            ret = requests.post(url, data, head)
            print(ret.content)
            socketIO._close()
        socketIO = SocketIO('http://192.168.2.36', 5200, LoggingNamespace)
        socketIO.on('s_id', getSID)
        socketIO.wait()
        SendInvitation.destroy(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    chessGui = QApplication(sys.argv)
    UID = 1
    window = SendInvitation(UID)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(chessGui.exec_())
```

Comment: QThread is not a GUI, why do you call the show() or setMinimumSize() or setWindowTitle() method? Is that your real code?

Comment: That was by mistake.  Now I have edited the code. Actually, there was QMainWindow instead of QThread

Comment: @eyllanesc please see it once again it will be your great help if you can suggest me any other option.

Answer (score 1):

here I am add threading in this code for solve crashing window problem.now socket is running on thread so GUI window is not crashing.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QLineEdit, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QThread
import requests
import json
import sys
from socketIO_client_nexus import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
import logging
import requests
import threding

class SendInvitation(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, arg):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(240, 500))
        self.setWindowTitle("GetUserlist")

        self.userid = arg

        url = 'http://192.168.2.36:5200/get_userlist'
        head = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        data = {'user_id': self.userid}

        ret = requests.post(url, data, head)
        responcedict = json.loads(ret.content)
        print(responcedict)
        userData = responcedict['data']
        x=100
        y=100
        for i in userData:
            useridstring = str(i['user_id'])

            buttonname = QPushButton(useridstring, self)
            buttonname.move(20, y)
            y= y + 30

            buttonname = QPushButton(i['user_name'],self)
            buttonname.move(120, x)
            x = x+30
        self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel.setText('Enter Opponant ID: ')
        self.line1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line1.move(120, 25)
        self.line1.resize(100, 25)
        self.nameLabel.move(20, 20)

        OKbutton = QPushButton('OK', self)
        OKbutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        OKbutton.resize(100,32)
        OKbutton.move(80, 60)

    def clickMethod(self):
        self.OpponantID = self.line1.text()
        print("Invitation send ID:" + self.OpponantID)
        # return OpponantID
        thread = threading.Thread(target = self.socket)
        thread.start()

    def socket(self):
        def getSID(args):
            # print(userid)
            NOWsocketID = args
            print("YOUR SocketID: " + NOWsocketID)
            url = 'http://192.168.2.36:5200/start_game'
            head = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            data = {'user_id': self.userid,
                    'opponent_id': self.OpponantID,
                    'socket_id': NOWsocketID}
            ret = requests.post(url, data, head)
            print(ret.content)
            socketIO._close()
        socketIO = SocketIO('http://192.168.2.36', 5200, LoggingNamespace)
        socketIO.on('s_id', getSID)
        socketIO.wait()
        SendInvitation.destroy(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    chessGui = QApplication(sys.argv)
    UID = 1
    window = SendInvitation(UID)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(chessGui.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears leaving `socketIO.wait()` set to empty has you waiting forever. (a hang technically?)

Try setting it to, `socketIO.wait(seconds=2)`

I am new, so ignore me if this is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, your logic is absolutely true. But I have also tried with adding seconds Like I have added socketIO.wait(seconds=2)   but by adding that window is not crashing but even it is not responsive for 2 seconds as socket is waiting

Comment: Thread is one way to do this task as thread is able to run GUI and Socket simultaniously. that might solve the issue. Is there any other way that you think can solve the issue?